# foolproof RequiredIF for any value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see foolproof have some good custom validation, and was looking at the RequiredIF one.

I can't see any examples or confirmation on this, can it be used to reference a text box and return an error if any value has been entered in it?

for example if a phone number is broken up into 3 boxes, country, area and number, if number has any value at all then are is required? or does this only work if you specify the value for the requiredIf?

Comment: The `[RequiredIf]` attribute is a conditional attribute based on the value of another property in your model. For example `[RequiredIf("Gender", "Male")]public string SomeProperty { get; set; }` means that if the value of property `Gender` is `"Male"` the `SomeProperty` must have a value (otherwise it can be `null`)

Comment: ok thanks a lot mate